# How to approach the dispatching of open sockets to threads in Java?

Tags: java, jersey, distributed-computing

we need to create a ListeningDispatcher that accepts connections on the port P from N clients (for now they are local, so they are identified just by a port, but it could be an address later). My approach would be to put a .accept() call, retrieve the Socket, start a new thread and let it handle the message from the Socket. So if we have n clients in our distributed system (broadcast based, with a logical token ring), i would keep N threads, with N Sockets.

My mate is arguing that this would keep too many threads open and it's better to start a new thread on every new connection but instead of keeping the thread running, closing the socket and stop the thread after the message is recieved. This way, we would use less threads but we would have to create a new Socket for every message.

I think this would degrade the communication because it takes time to open a new Socket.

Consider that the system must be scalable and has an heavy communication part, because every event is broadcasted to every client.

Note: we can't use ThreadPools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My approach would be to put a .accept() call, retrieve the Socket,
>   start a new thread and let it handle the message from the Socket.

Don't start a new thread. Use a [thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and reuse threads.

> This way, we would use less thread but we would have to create a new
>   Socket for every message

For each client you use a different client socket via `accept`. This sentence does not make sense

Comment: Forgot to say, we can't use ThreadPools, otherwise it would be really easy.

Comment: @Chobeat:What do you mean you can't? Why not?

Comment: Because it's a sort of didactic project and we can't use complex classes (on the aspect of synchronization) such as ThreadPool. I know it sounds dumb, but still...

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to reply. Maybe i've understood where our error is. Let us discuss a second and i will be back to you.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to make a decision between fewer threads and fewer new connections. Your 'mate' might want to ponder why HTTP keep-alive was invented. It was invented to re-use connections where possible rather than pay the cost of creating new ones.

Comment: That's exactly what i thought but we had no means to decide what is more costly, even if i was pretty sure that creating new connections would be extremely expensive.